# safely archive guzzle responses

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to take an array of image urls and use guzzle to fetch them and add them to a `ZipArchive`. I've done a very small amount of async conscious coding in the past and am unsure of how to best handle this in php.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

$requests = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $requests[] = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $url);
};

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$pool = new \GuzzleHttp\Pool($client, $requests, [
   'concurrency' => 5,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response) use ($zip) {
        $id = \Rhumsaa\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
        $zip->addFromString($id, (string)$response->getBody());
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
         // no-op
    }
]);

$pool->promise()->wait();

$zip->close();
```

Because these requests will be sent concurrently, do I need to somehow lock/unlock access to `$zip` inside the `fulfilled` callback? If so, how?

Bonus(unrelated) question: What's the best way to go about getting the appropriate extension of the fetched image from the `$response` if it's not in the url? Is there a cleaner way than inspecting the Content-Type and using a map? Ex:

```
$extensions = [
    'image/png' => '.png',
    'image/jpeg' => '.jpeg',
    'image/gif' => '.gif',
    // etc
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need to somehow lock/unlock access to $zip inside the fulfilled callback?

No, you don't.  The promises are resolved asynchronously, sure, but it is all in a single thread. When you do:

```
$zip->addFromString($id, (string)$response->getBody());
```

you are blocking php here until the file is added to the ZIP archive.

> What's the best way to go about getting the appropriate extension of the fetched image from the $response if it's not in the url?

I think that check `Content-Type` is the correct way to do it. You can do this with:

```
$contentType = explode(';', $response->getHeaderLine('Content-Type'), 2)[0];
$extensions = [
    'image/png' => '.png',
    'image/jpeg' => '.jpeg',
    'image/gif' => '.gif',
    // etc
];

// check for $extensions[$contentType];
```

Comment: awesome. Thank you Federico